# Create jar to exe with MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, swing, deployment, installation

How do I create an installer exe file with MySql DB included? What is the best way to install the database along with my application?

Comment: I would say the best option is not to include mysql in your installer. List MySql as a requirement, add its installer separately to your media / download page, but let people chose to install MySql or use their (already installed) MySqls. Your installer should just ask for the JDBC data.

Comment: *"How do I create a exe.."*  Use .NET.  It specializes in them.  OTOH for Java, an EXE is a step backwards, as it will only work on one OS.  Does your app. have a GUI?  What is the purpose of the DB and how will it be used?

Comment: You can use an embedded database, like Derby, i.o. MySQL. Then the installation is very flexible.

Comment: @JoopEggen  Re. the embedded DB. Does that only work for a 'read-only' DB?

Comment: Im using mysql now,yes i have GUI, This application have to run WINDOWS,LINUX and MAC.I do not have any idea about this,This is a dictionary application so it's database is relatively large.

Comment: @AndrewThompson no, "normally" a read-write DB becomes an initial filling (schemata and data). In general it automatically resides in the user directory. But all play variants are possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use two separate technologies, one (like [JSmooth](http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/)) to create an exe from a jar (this exe is only a wrapper around your jar, which will be uncompressed at runtime), and another (like [NSIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nullsoft_Scriptable_Install_System)) for creating a "setup exe": an installer program that can include your previously created jar-exe and and any other programs, such as a database.

Of course, this would be a Windows-only solution, Windows exe files do not run on Linux/Mac. Jar files run everywhere (if Java is installed)

Comment: I dont know how to do it? I am using innosetup and i can't find a way 
to install mysql in that.

Comment: I think it should be possible to install MySQL with Inno Setup, I suggest that you ask that in a separate and specific question.

Answer (score 1):

> yes i have GUI,..

Then you need [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) for deploying it (to Windows, OS X and *nix).

JWS offers the `ExtensionInstallerService` that might be used to invoke an installer for the DB, and a `PersistenceService` for storing any connection details.  See demos. of both in the [Java Web Start examples](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html).